# SAS Unix Shell Script - Print Contents of Table or Macro Variables

Tags: unix, sas, mailx

I figured it out.

```
GREPOUT=`grep "NOTE: Table $TABLE created," $LOGFILE | awk '{print $6}'`
NIW=`grep "SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable NIW resolves to" $LOGFILE | awk '{print $0}'`

if [ "$GREPOUT" -gt "0" ]; then
echo "$NIW" |\

$MAILX -s "SUCESSFUL BATCH RUN: $PROG $RPTDATE" $MAILLIST
fi
```

from the body of the sent email

SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable NIW resolves to            8

My script runs a SAS code and sends out an email after it completes.

I'm looking to print the contents of a table or list of macro variables in the email.

The SAS code has a %put *all*; statement at the end so all macro variables are listed in the log.

Thanks.

```
#If it's gotten this far, we can safely grab the number of rows
#of output from $LOGFILE.
GREPOUT=`grep "NOTE: Table $TABLE created," $LOGFILE | awk '{print $6}'`
NIW=`grep "GLOBAL NIW" $LOGFILE | '(print $6)'`
if [ "$GREPOUT" -gt "0" ]; then
#echo "$GREPOUT rows found in $TABLE." |\
echo "$NIW NIW" |\

$MAILX -s "SUCESSFUL BATCH RUN: $PROG $RPTDATE" $MAILLIST
else
echo "$GREPOUT rows found in $TABLE." |\
$MAILX -s "SUCESSFUL BATCH RUN: $PROG $RPTDATE" $MAILLIST
fi
```

Comment: a typical `mail(x)` can read messages for std in, so you can do `echo "$GREPOUT" | mailx -s ...`, or `mailx -s ... < tmpFile` and numerous other variants. You'll always want to quote your any variables that you might send to `mail` to keep the formatting. Good luck.

Comment: hmmm... is there a way to echo the cells from the table in the emal?echo $TABLE |\ just shows the table name

Comment: what i have works, but just looks sloppy in the email.    SYMBOLGEN: Macro variable ABC resolves to            8
SYMBOLGEN: Macro variable XYZ_ABC resolves to         1.56
the email would look much nicer if i could just echo the table contents instead of referencing macro variables via call symput and echo

Comment: sorry, I don't have experience with SAS. But unix tools are standarized to process lines of data.  Consider editting your question to include a minimal sample output from SAS and its SYBMOLGEN stuff AND what you expect the email to look like and it should be possible to give you  a reasonably formatted email. If you're talking about HTML tables, however, that is consultant level problem. Good luck.

Comment: Why not send the email from within SAS?